# How to delegate a document to a user via Samson using DQL

Tags: documentum, documentum-dql

I'm new with writing DQL queries, and trying to find documentation for Samson 1.0 is a huge pain.

So, can someone help me figure out how to delegate a Documentum task via Samson using DQL?

Also, if anyone could point me to where I can find documentation for DQL and Samson I would be extremely grateful.

Here is a link to Documentum documentation: https://austria.emc.com/collateral/TechnicalDocument/docu56505.pdf

Comment: Is Samson DQL and API editor like stated in the link? https://msroth.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/documentum-open-source-utilities/

Comment: check this out http://mallikarjunareddypoli.blogspot.com/2013/09/delegate-api-to-reassign-workflow.html

Comment: Yep that's it! That command seems right, but I don't seem to get any feedback on if it worked or not

Comment: Hi @Miki, I keep getting the following error when running my script: "Cannot perform reassign method on supplied object of id (0900f3eb81483d50) since it is not of type (dmi_workitem)."

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Miki for the links!

In order to delegate a task using DQL in Samson. Make sure you call the commands using the A+ (API prompt) instead of the D+ (DQL prompt). Once there, you can delegate a task using the Documentum API call:

```
delegate,c,<workitem_id>,<user_name>
```